# javascript Math.abs() different behaviour

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I do not understand what's going on in these cases:

```
Math.abs(40.35 * 100)
->4035
Math.abs(40.36 * 100)
->4036
Math.abs(40.37 * 100)
->4036.9999999999995
Math.abs(40.38 * 100)
->4038.0000000000005
Math.abs(40.39 * 100)
->4039
```

Why does this happen?
I though `math.abs()` returns absolute values (?).

Thank you a lot

EDIT*
Thanks for the referencing link, did not find anything like that

Comment: Nothing to do with `abs`. Remove it and observe the same results.

Comment: `math.abs(x)` changes negative numbers to positive numbers.  Did you want `math.round(x)` instead?

Comment: The same thing happens in decimal if you multiply 1/3 by 3 -- you get .99999... rather than 1. What don't you understand about finite precision?